# create my own gui window for sublime plugin

Tags: user-interface, sublimetext

I want to create my own window for sublime text plugin 
for example the desired window will be similar to the color picker window but of course with different elements(images ,text etc ..)

is that possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible, otherwise Color Picker and other plugins wouldn't work.

It needs to be an external program, as the versions of Python included with Sublime don't include Tkinter or any other graphics toolkits. You'll need to compile your program for all three supported platforms if you want it to work on them, and figure out some way of distributing the executables. You'll also need to do a lot of testing to verify it works on different versions of Windows, OS X, and Linux, with their different versions of shared libraries, etc.